# Не показываются картинки после .append(rsp) ответа html от ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется ajax запрос, который возвращает html вида

```js
let loadAdvantages = () => {
    let wrapper = $('#js-main-service-advantages');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/request/show_service_advantages/',
        type: 'post',
        success: rsp => {
            wrapper.html(rsp);
        }
    })
};
loadAdvantages();
```

```html
<div class="m_grid--column">
    <div class="b_superiority--item"> <span class="b_superiority--icons" src="/img/svg/superiority/professional.svg"></span>
        <div class="b_superiority--title"> Профессионализм сотрудников </div>
        <p class="b_superiority--text"> Текст профессионализма </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

После загрузки появляется только текст, без изображений, они не рендерятся, хотя в коде есть. Куда копать?

Comment: А где у вас `js-main-service-advantages` ?? покажите что приходит в `rp`. Может быть у вас с путями проблема?

Comment: В rsp html, который я привел под js. js-main-service-advantages находится на странице, при загрузке он гарантированно существует. Картинки при переходе по пути открываются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="b_superiority--icons" src="/img/svg/superiority/professional.svg"></span>
```

У элемента `span` нет атрибута `src`.

Comment: Совсем голова к вечеру не варит. Спасибо! Заменил на background-image

Comment: @СвиридовАлексей Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.